# Why is a question about accessing a SMB share from Nautilus assessed as OT?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am talking about

https://askubuntu.com/questions/453158/samba-share-opens-in-gedit-rather-than-nautilus-ubuntu-14-04

which was closed as OT ("not about Ubuntu") because the OP hadn't made it clear from where he was trying to access the share.

After his edit I voted to reopen (that's what the system is telling me anyway), my vote seems to have expired and I cannot vote to reopen it again.

Now I see no reason for it to be OT (except maybe it is a bug) - can it be reopened?

<sub>Disclaimer: I stumble over the same issue every now and then myself.</sub>

Comment: Does not seem closed to me ;-) This might be better asked in chat though; mosttimes there is somewhere there that can re-open something like that

Comment: Note that I voted for unclear, it still can't be answered if OP doesn't provide more information.

Comment: @Braiam Then ask for that information. You shouldn't be closing otherwise good questions as unclear if you don't explain what is needed. That is a big no no.

Comment: @Seth then you shouldn't reopen question without asking "what else could be wrong".

Comment: @Braiam I did ask myself that, and I didn't find anything worth leaving closed for.

Answer (score 1):

### Sure.

I'm not sure it's really an Ubuntu problem, but until we know I think it can be reopened since the OP is (now) clearly using Ubuntu.

Comment: Blindly reopening questions is bad, questions shouldn't get reopened just because "it looks fine" or "the current close reason doesn't apply" it should be reopened on the basis of "can be reasonably answered?"

Comment: @Braiam I'm not blindly reopening it, we don't close all the questions and only reopen them once someone has an answer. That is stupid. I see what you are saying about unclear, but without giving the OP a chance we don't close it as unclear (I'm *not* saying we wait for clarification, I'm saying you need to request clarification before voting to close). It was wrongly closed, and until further notice it seems to be ok, albeit requiring some clarification.